# ToggleButton does not have IsDefault property Wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Wpf button has IsDefault property, I can set IsDefault to true or false.

But Toggle Button does not IsDefault property

`<ToggleButton x:Name = "tb" Content = "Toggle"  Checked = "HandleCheck"  **IsDefault="true"**/>`

How can i set IsDefault property to ToggleButton, or How to Add IsDefault property to ToggleButton

I want to set IsDefault to false, enter key never trigger it, even after the toggle button is clicked or chosen.

Comment: That property makes no sense on a ToggleButton. Hence it isn't there.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're trying to achieve. The default button is equivalent to a submit button. The "bam i'm finished, done, update my data please" button.

Comment: i have 10 buttons, 6 of them are toggle buttons. and 4 of them are normal buttons, i want one of the normal button always be default default button. Even after i clicked toggle button. then i press enter key, the enter key still trigger normal button, which is Default button.